# Can anyone show or clarify

Tags: analysis

Can any anyone clarify or prove that if the derivative of a function $f$ is strictly positive then the function $f$ is strictly monotone increasing. I am really sure that the converse is not true as the converse will not be true for the function $f(x)=x^3$.
I thank every one prove the first part of the this problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the mean value theorem.  If the function $f$ is not strictly increasing, what does this theorem tell you?

Comment: Do you mean that by mean value theorem that there is $c$ such that $f^'(c)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{(x_2)-(x_1)}>0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If $f$ is not strictly increasing, you can find points $x_1$ and $x_2$ with what properties?  And then was does that imply about $f'(c)$?